# Why don't protocols in Swift use brackets instead of associated types?

Tags: swift

Why did the Swift language designers decide to make the syntax this:

```
protocol Container {
    associatedtype Item
    mutating func append(_ item: Item)
    var count: Int { get }
    subscript(i: Int) -> Item { get }
}
```

Rather than this:

```
protocol Container<Item> {
    mutating func append(_ item: Item)
    var count: Int { get }
    subscript(i: Int) -> Item { get }
}
```

The latter would seem to be much more consistent with other uses of generics in Swift.

Comment: Good question. Maybe they preferred the other due to neatness? Not sure...

Comment: Ahh, I missed that. Thanks!